# Find index and value of item with latest date

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, reactjs

My API structure

```
let datas = [{
  end_date: '2019-12-16'
}, {
  end_date: '2018-12-16'
}];
let latestData = datas.filter( /* I need an index number of item based on latest date */ );
```

Looking for vanilla JavaScript code

Comment: so do want to sort it by date or return just the last date?

Comment: could you start with .sort() first and than check index. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
latestData.sort((a,b) => {b.end_date - a.end_date});

Comment: Get latest date and correspond index @MWO

Comment: @khmub I tried but coudnt luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `.sort()`.

If you sort the array in order of recent date, the most recent date will come first in the array. It is recommended to use `.sort()`.

```js
const datas = [{end_date: '2018-12-16'}, {end_date: '2020-12-16'}, {end_date: '2019-12-16'}, {end_date: '2017-12-16'} ];
const latestData = datas.sort((a, b) => {
  return new Date(b.end_date) - new Date(a.end_date);
});
console.log(latestData[0]); // {end_date: '2020-12-16'}
```

Edit.

If you want to get only index of origin array.

```js
const datas = [{end_date: '2018-12-16'}, {end_date: '2020-12-16'}, {end_date: '2019-12-16'}, {end_date: '2017-12-16'} ];
const timestamps = datas.map((obj) => {
  return +new Date(obj.end_date);
});
const latest = +new Date(Math.max(...timestamps));
const latestDataIndex = timestamps.indexOf(latest);

console.log(datas[latestDataIndex]);
```

Plus.

You can use for loop to browse array only once without sorting it.

```js
const datas = [{end_date: '2018-12-16'}, {end_date: '2020-12-16'}, {end_date: '2019-12-16'}, {end_date: '2017-12-16'}, {end_date: '2021-12-16'} ];
let minDate = datas[0];
let index = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
  const currentData = datas[i];
  if (new Date(minDate.end_date) < new Date(currentData.end_date)) {
    minDate = currentData;
    index = i;
  }
}
console.log(datas[index]);
```

Comment: much better if you can post this as a snippet

Comment: Thanks , but can I get index value of item based on latest year

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.sort() with localeCompare() to compare the strings

```js
let datas = [ 
    {
        end_date: '2019-12-16' 
},
    {
    end_date: '2019-12-16' 
    },
    {
    end_date: '2022-12-16' 
    }
]

const res = datas.map((date, i)=>(date.i=i, date)).sort((a,b)=>{
    return  b.end_date.localeCompare(a.end_date);
})

console.log(res[0]);
```

Alternativelyyou you can use an more performant Array.reduce() approach.

```js
let datas = [ { end_date: '2019-12-16' }, { end_date: '2019-12-16' }, { end_date: '2022-12-16' } ]

const r=datas.reduce((acc, curr, i)=>{
    if(Object.keys(acc).length === 0){
        return {...curr, i: i};
    }else if(new Date(acc.end_date) < new Date(curr.end_date)){
       return {...curr, i: i};
    }else return acc;
},{});

console.log(r);
```

Comment: Thanks , but can I get index value of item based on latest year

Comment: @Hunter yes i updated the code

Comment: I don't like the sort idea but if you're using it then localeCompare is absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: @SalmanA yes there are many ways. alternatively i added an reduce approach

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to sort (snark removed). Iterate the array and keep track of the index that contains the largest value. Here is an implementation using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
let datas = [{
  end_date: '2018-12-16'
}, {
  end_date: '2020-12-16'
}, {
  end_date: '2019-12-16'
}, {
  end_date: '2017-12-16'
}];
let index = datas.reduce((retval, item, index, array) => retval === -1 || array[retval].end_date < item.end_date ? index : retval, -1);
console.log(index);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use  Math.max but unix time required

```
Math.max.apply(Math, array.map(function(o) { return o.end_date; }))
```